# how to stretch a textview along the screen horizontally

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I want to have a textview spans along the screen horizontally. so i wrote the code of the layout as shown in the code belwo. but the problem is, the textview is not stretched along the screen horizontally, it looks like
as shown in the image below

please help me to solve this problem

**layout**:

```
<TableLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/actMain_status_layout_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
        android:text="Status" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**image**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would add your TableRow a width. Possibly , `match_parent`.
This is because the parent of the TextView is the TableRow itself, not the TableLayout, which is its grandparent.

Answer (score 0):

Add `layout_width` to your `TableRow` like this :

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
        android:text="Status" />
</TableRow>
```

Hope this helps. :D